# R indexing and list translation

Tags: r, list

i have a list with indexes like this:

```
> mid_cp
   [1]  3065  4871 13153 15587 18100 24010 26324 25648 38195 38196 39384 42237 45686 54217 55032 63684 62800  9134 35261 36449 36866 53968 16969
  [24] 43529 46995 52351  4174  7011 18962 18151 18889 24036 32916 34061 34815 36866 51973 55802 53593 55421 56615    88   150   161   192   781
  [47]   830  1300  1573  2396  2784  2547  3214  3135  3297  3301  4053  4249  4919  5856  6297  7328  7621  7708  8063  8219  8864  8887  9201
  [70]  9214  9533 10334 10301 11235 10529 11356 10566 10872 12228 12250 12507 12048 12643 12913 13224 14297 16772 15363 18759 18979 16264 17363
  [93] 20732 17971 22194 22422 19417 22903 22929 23087 19627 19961 23954 24297 25422 25423 25704 25765 25780 22769 22796 26871 27095 23789 24066
 [116] 24069 27423 24366 24600 24871 25110 28374 26280 27873 29722 28839 29063 31031 31150 31546 32491 30356 33045 30863 33555 34201 34404 34684
 [139] 35498 32912 33207 35874 33488 33716 36761 34543 36807 37000 35157 38195 38196 38458 36438 36619 39484 40109 37532 40143 40160 40458 41257
 [162] 38434 38653 41866 41899 39429 42818 40001 43398 43441 40282 40566 43979 43996 40793 40806 40992 41065 41102 41330 41964 46322 43351 46670
```

and I have a table like this:

```
> head(movie.cp)
                                               name  id
252                         $ (Dollars) (The Heist) 252
253                   $5 a Day (Five Dollars a Day) 253
1                                             $9.99   1
254                               $windle (Swindle) 254
255    &#034;BBC2 Playhouse&#034; Caught on a Train 255
256 &#034;Independent Lens&#034;  Race to Execution 256
```

How do i get the mid_cp list to be a name list using the movie.cp table?
P.S.: I am completely newbie regarding R

Comment: are the numbers in `mid_cp` equivalent to `movie.cp$id`? if so try `mid_cp <- movie.cp$name[match(mid_cp,movie.cp$id)]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielO, just what i needed

Comment: your welcome, I've included it as an answer. Mark it accepted to help people in the future with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are the numbers in `mid_cp` equivalent to `movie.cp$id`? if so try `mid_cp <- movie.cp$name[match(mid_cp,movie.cp$id)]`